# Asynctask status always showing running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to execute an asynctask after finishing the first task. But when printing the status the of the first task it always shows RUNNING.If  execute both tasks parallel only smaller task will be executed. I am running both in activity oncreate method.Any idea?

here is my code sample

```
public class test extends Activity 
 {

    ExecuteTask1 task1; 
    ExecuteTask2 task2; 
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            task1 = new ExecuteTask1();
            task1.execute(token);
            System.out.println(task1.getStatus());
            if(task1.getStatus() ==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
            {
                task2 = new ExecuteTask2();
                task2.execute(token);
            }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code right now, you aren't giving task1 time to finish. Start task2 from the `onPostExecute` method of task1. (You'll have to modify the code in class ExecuteTask1 for this to work.)

Alternatively, have task1 call back to your activity (or post a message to it or something) in `onPostExecute` so your activity can then start task2.

Comment: Might be slightly off-topic but can it be that getStatus() returns Running if an AsyncTask has been cancelled prior oO ? At least that's what I am getting right now, despite having cancelled my AsyncTask (unless the same task is somehow being auto-revived xD).

Comment: @Zainodis - `AsyncTask.getStatus()` can indeed return `RUNNING` after `cancel()` has been called and returns `true`. The call to `cancel()` may, for instance, call `interrupt()` on the underlying thread or may simply set the `isCancelled()` flag for the `AsyncTask`, but the status of the `AsyncTask` won't change until the underlying thread notices the interrupt or change in flag value and actually exits. That's why the docs recommend that `doInBackground()` should periodically check the value of `isCancelled()` and "finish the task as early as possible."

Answer (score 1):

That's because you get status of `task1` right after you start it - you need to call second AsyncTask from first one's `onPostExecute()`, using [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or some other way.

Comment: Since onPostExecute runs on the event thread, there's no need to use a handler.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask get method is blocking.
Then you can also write `task1.get()` and then `task2.execute()`. Such that, you remove the dependence of the task1 with the task2 in the AsyncTask implementation