# How to handle multiple asyc request in java for android?

Tags: java, android

Suppose if i have multiple url to get the information data either in xml or json. How can i manage the queue for maintaining the each request?

Example

Screen 1 --requests----> URL1 ----> DATA From Server
Screen 2 --requests----> URL2 ----> DATA FROM Server

Now, If user changes the screen frequently in that case how can i manage their multiple request asynchronously?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 async tasks one fetch data from URL1 and onpost execute of first async task call the second task.

please check this link

[Asynctask status always showing running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337419/asynctask-status-always-showing-running)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented with success an App with a similar need completely decoupling the data loading part form the UI.
Use a plain `Thread` (or eventually a limited pool of) which you could feed for example with a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Then use the `AsyncTask` just to eventually wait for available data and notify the UI for updates, or use the `View.post()` method.