# How can I run the same Asynctask one after one finished

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask

Firstly, i have an arraylist (the data from firebase)which contains stock Strings.

Then i need to pass those stock strings to the asynctask . The asynctask is going to get the json from an url so i can get other stock information for constructing my listview.

The problem is that i dont know how to perform the asynctask one by one. I read several posts on the forum but it not suitable for my case.

Here is my Asynctask code:

```
public class SearchingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, String>> {
private static final String TAG = SearchingAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();
Searching listener;
int i=0;

public void setListener(Searching listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(String... arg0){
    HashMap<String, String> hashResult = new HashMap<>();
    getMoney18DailyJson(hashResult, arg0[0]);
    getMoney18RealJson(hashResult, arg0[0]);

    return hashResult;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> result){
    listener.getInfo(result);

}
```

Here is my searching interface:

```
public interface Searching {
void getInfo(HashMap<String, String> info); }
```

The place that i want to call my Asynctask

```
public class LoadBookMarkList implements Searching{
public  static ArrayList<String> quote = new ArrayList<>();

public HashMap mark=new HashMap();
private FirebaseAuth auth;
public int i;

public void inti() {
    i=0;

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("BookMark");
    ref.keepSynced(true);
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    getQuote((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
}

public void getQuote(Map<String,Object> users)  {

    //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()){

        //Get user map
        Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
        //Get phone field and append to list
        quote.add(singleUser.get("quote").toString());
    }

    SearchingAsyncTask searchBookMark = new SearchingAsyncTask();
    searchBookMark.setListener(LoadBookMarkList.this);
    searchBookMark.execute("0"+quote.get(i)); 
    //I want to loop the execute() so i can input all arraylist element in to
    //the asynctask

}

@Override
public void  getInfo(HashMap<String, String> info){

        mark.put("Quote", quote.get(i));
        mark.put("ComName", info.get("name"));
        mark.put("Price", info.get("np"));
        mark.put("Increase","-0.5");
        mark.put("InPer","-0.5");
        Search.bookMarkData.add(mark); //for Listview 
}
```

}

Comment: `Object result =  searchBookMark.execute("0"+quote.get(i)).get();`
but it will block your Main Thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049087/9186864 explains a lot for you.

Comment: I try this before, but i have the problem that the asynctask always stay in running and never go to finishing stage....

Comment: `//I want to loop the execute() so i can input all arraylist element in to
    //the asynctask` ??? Unclear what you want. If you want a loop than make a loop. After that you can tell if it works or not and ask for comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database client, already runs all network operations in a background thread. This means that all operations take place without blocking your main thread. Putting it in an `AsyncTask` does not give any additional benefits.

If you want to search your database based on a keyword, follow these steps:

1. Create a new query based on the new filter

   ```
   Query query = yourRef.orderByChild("yourField").equalTo(searchText);
   ```
2. Attach a listener to this query.
3. Create a new adapter with the results of this new query, or update the existing one.